# Silly syntax error c++

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm completely new to C++.

Bashing my head against this error for over an hour. Probably someone with experience can see right through it.

The following code gives an error:

```
class TimeTravellingCellar { 

private:

public:
  int determineProfit (int [] profit, int [] decay) { 
    int N = sizeof(profit)/sizeof(decay); 
    int max = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) { 
        if (i == j) continue; 
        if (profit [i] - decay [j] > max) 
          max = profit [i] - decay [j]; 
      } 
    } 
    return max; 
  } 
}
```

Visual Studio Express puts a red line under `profit` in the parameters of `determineProfit` and says:

`expected a ')' before identifier profit`.

I will appreciate some help.
Thanks!

Comment: You are writing C# declarations.  It is `int profit[]` or `int* profit`.

Comment: Remember to add an int main() if you're trying to compile & link :)

Comment: You have a logical problem as well, I made an edit.  Errr, @Neil ninja'd me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't declare arrays like that in C++, the `[]` needs to go after the name.
Also note you need to have a semicolon after the class declaration.

```
class TimeTravellingCellar { 

private:

public:
  int determineProfit (int profit[], int decay[]) { 
    int N = sizeof(profit)/sizeof(decay); 
    int max = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) { 
        if (i == j) continue; 
        if (profit [i] - decay [j] > max) 
          max = profit [i] - decay [j]; 
      } 
    } 
    return max; 
  } 
};
```

Edit: also remember that sizeof(pointer) will return the number of bytes of the pointer type, not the number of elements in the array. So if you have an `int` array, `sizeof(array) == sizeof(int)`. Your `N` value will always equal 1.

Comment: *also remember that sizeof(array) will return the number of bytes in the array*, actually, in this example, `sizeof(profit) == sizeof(decay)`, i.e., `sizeof(int*)`.  The arrays have decayed to pointers, the size is unknown in the function.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I was thinking of it in the context of not a function argument. `int foo[10]; sizeof(foo)==40`.

Answer (score 12):

You are declaring your arrays as if this were c#.  It should be

```
int profit[]
```

Or

```
int *profit
```

You'll hit this one next.  You need to terminate your class with a semi-colon.

```
class Foo { 

};  <----
```

The *next* problem you have is logical, not syntactic.  This does not do what you think it does:

```
int N = sizeof(profit)/sizeof(decay);
```

You are taking the `sizeof` two pointers, not the size of the arrays.  You actually have:

```
int N = 4/4  /* assumes sizeof int == 4 */
```

You need to pass in the size of your to the function as well (or, better yet; stop using arrays and use a `vector<T>`.)

When you take an "array" as an argument to your function it actually decays to a pointer to the array type (an array proper cannot be passed to a function).  So it follows that:

```
void Foo( int array[] ) {
    size_t arrSize = sizeof(array);
    // arrSize == 4 for a 32-bit system, i.e., sizeof(int*)

    int a[100];
    size_t actualSizeInBytes = sizeof(a);
    // actualSizeInBytes == 400, i.e., 4 * 100 as an int occupies 4 bytes
}
```

Next, this line causes your first iteration to always be skipped.  Not sure if that is intentional:

```
if (i == j) continue;
```

Comment: @Lost_DM: No, it doesn't.  Those are the only two syntactic problems.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
 int determineProfit (int [] profit, int [] decay) {
```

Change it into:

```
int determineProfit (int profit[], int decay[]) {
```

or

```
int determineProfit (int* profit, int* decay) {
```

and add a closing `;`

If you do that and add a main, of course:

```
int main() {}
```

then you can compile your code - I just tried it with g++.

Answer (score 1):

Try `int determineProfit (int* profit, int* decay)` because for formal arguments, arrays and pointers are almost alike.

Comment: "Almost alike" but definitely not the same. He is using `sizeof`, and `sizeof(intptr) == 4`, whereas `sizeof(intarray) == 4 * length`.

Comment: @jli: It's actually exactly the same in this context.

Comment: Yeah I know, I answered this in your previous comment to me.

Comment: @jli: Just saw that, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are associated with the variable name, not the type. The first line should be

```
int determineProfit (int profit[], int decay[]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial on [arrays in C](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) may be enlightening, especially as regards the passing of array parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
int determineProfit (int[] profit int [] decay
```

here is your error - the above statement is wrong; it should be like this

```
int determineProfit (int profit[], int decay[])
```